# Is modifying or adding app settings to azure app service running on linux container will recycle the site

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice, linux-containers

We use containerized .net core applications on linux app service plans. I am trying to figure if any changes introduced to the app settings (modification or add) will cause the app service to recycle.
There is a similar question I found here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f15b207b-c063-46e5-b87a-2b157641c8c4/does-changing-an-app-setting-and-saving-restart-the-app but it's unclear if it's related to linux app service plans. Also, this one [Change an Azure App Setting using the portal without a restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481926/change-an-azure-app-setting-using-the-portal-without-a-restart) but again there is nothing indicating if it's linux and if it's a containerized application.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever changes/modifications made to the application settings for any windows or Linux container apps, it will restart your application.

**Reason:**
Linux application is all about containers hence making app setting changes dont alter image but it changes environment variable.

When you deploy your application it creates its own application domain and set environment variables to use while execution.
If we make any changes in environment variable by any configuration file means it does cause restart.

**How to avoid application restart?**
Think of storing the configuration values at some other places. May be using Azure key vault, Azure appconfiguration or some constant file inside application or any other service such that the web app will not restart.